How to run Gemini in Android Studio
In new android studio jellyfish 2023.3.1 RC 2 i'm trying to run Gemini but it's not available in my country, how to get round the problem?
I tried to change country and language in google account setting, but it didn't help me

Try VPN and check

Welcome Oleg! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

Here's how to set up Gemini:
Download the latest version of Android Studio Jellyfish or higher.

Recommended: Agree to send data to Google so we can better understand
how effective Gemini is. Give permission to share data either when
you first install Android Studio or later at File > Settings >
Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data Sharing (Android
Studio > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data
Sharing on macOS).

To launch Gemini, open or start an Android Studio project and click
View > Tool Windows > Gemini.

Sign in to your Google account when asked, if you aren't already
signed in. The chat box appears and you can start using Gemini's
interactive, conversational interface.


